# Error de paginación en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Mientras hacia una serie de modificaciones a un wordpress, me encontré con un error de paginación en el blog que no logro resolver.  Cuando le das a cargar los post de la pagina siguiente, este vuelve a cargar los de la misma, duplicandolos  y no dejando acceder a los mas antiguos.

Después de buscar entre los ajustes de lectura del wordpress en busca de alguna opción  que provocase el problema, no encontré nada. Y en los ajustes del mismo blog solo encontré que el ***tipo de redireccionamiento*** de la pagina esta fijado en ***301 permanent***.  Cuando intento cambiar la opción por cualquiera de las otras, los cambios no se aplican ni en el backoffice ni en la pagina.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Buscando posibles causas, me encontré con una serie de artículos que hablaban sobre la actualización 4.4.1 de wordpress. Dicha actualización provocaría un error de paginación en el blog, aplicando un redireccionamiento 301 como el que me encontré y que seria la causa de no poder acceder a las siguientes paginas.

El wordpress tiene una actualización 4.8.1

***¿Es la actualización 4.4.1 de wordpress la causa de mi problema?***

Mis conocimientos de wordpress son limitados y me gustaría descartar opciones mas sencillas que podrían provocar el mismo problema y que podría no estar teniendo en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que sea un error en la query cuando intentas traer los posts.
Puedes intentar algo como:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'paged'          => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'posts' );
endwhile;

if ( function_exists( 'page_navi' ) ) {
    ?>

    <div id="pagination">
        <?php page_navi(); ?>
    </div>
<?php }
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Para más detalles sobre las paginación de WordPress, haz click [aquí](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination).

Answer (score 0):

Nos pasa el mismo problema en la paginación de nuestro blog que tiene unas 130 entradas. Por el momento hemos aumentado a 50 el número de entradas a mostrar para evitar problemas de SEO, es un problema de la última versión de Wordpress, la solución la hemos encontrado aquí: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35344#comment:16

Comment: ¿Es necesario el enlace a tu página web? ¿Aporta algo a la respuesta o simplemente estás intentando agregar publicidad?